# How can I make pie chart of high chart libarary unrotatable?

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I am using highchart library. I am using pie chart. What i want is that when I render pie chart, it should not rotate itself. the data points should adjust itself in the pie chart dynamically. Can it be done?

Comment: what do you mean by *the data points should adjust itself in the pie chart dynamically*?

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the rotation by using `animation: false`
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.animation

see [example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37kLt8kq/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            animation: false
        }
    }
});
```